# How to update ReadModel of an Aggregate that has an association with another Aggregate

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm trying to separate read and write models. In summary I have this 2 entities with an association between them:

```
//AgregateRoot
class ProfessionalFamily {
    private ProfessionalFamilyId id;
    private String name;
}

//AgregateRoot
class Group {
    private GroupId id;
    private String literal;
    private ProfessionalFamilyId professionalFamilyId; //ManyToOne association referenced by the ID of "professional-family"
}
```

The read model I'm using for return data in a Grid is the next one.

```
class GroupReadModel {
    private String id;
    private String groupLiteral;
    private String professionalFamilyName;
}
```

I want to use NoSql for ReadModel queries and separate them for the write models. But my headache is: with that approach, when a Group is created I fire an Event (GroupCreated) and an Event handler listen the Event and store de Read/View/Projection Model in the NoSql database. So my question is: If I need to update the ProfessionalFamilyName and this is related with more than, for example 1000 groups (there are many more groups), how can I update all the Groups in ReadModel who is related with the professionalFamily I've been updated? Most probably I'm not doing anything well.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoSql databases are usually not designed to support data normalization and even intentionally break with this concept. If you would use a relational database system you would usually normalize your data and to each group you would only store the id of the ProfessionalFamily rather than duplicating the name of the ProfessionalFamily in each group document. So in general, for NoSql database duplication is accepted.

But I think before deciding to go with NoSql or a relational database you should consider (at least) the following:

---

**Priority for speed of reads vs. writes**:

If you need your writes (in your case changes of the name) to be very fast as they happen very often and the read speed is of lower priority maybe NoSql is not the best choice. You could still look into technology such as MongoDB which provides some kind of hybrid approach and allows to normalize and index data to a certain extent.

Writes will usally be faster when having a normalized structure in a relational database whereas reads will normally be faster without normalization and duplication in a NoSql database. But this is of course dependent on the technologies at hand which you are comparing as well as the amount of entities (in your case Groups) we are talking about as well as the amount of cross-referenced data. If you need to do lots of joins during the reads due to normalization you read performance will usually be worse compared to Group documents where all required data is already there due to duplication.

---

**Control over the data structure/schema**

If you are the one who knows how the data will look like you might not need the advantage of a NoSql database which is very well suited for data structures that change frequently or you are not in control of. If this is not really the case you might not benefit enough from NoSql technology.

---

And in addition there is another thing to consider: ***how consistent does your read model data have to be***? As you are having some kind of event-sourcing approach I guess you are already embracing **eventual consistency**. That means not only the event processing is performed asynchronously but you could also accept that - getting back to your example - not all groups are being updated with the new family name at the same time but as well asynchronously or via some background jobs if it is not a problem that one Group still shows the old name while some other group already shows the new name for some time.

---

> Most probably I'm not doing anything well.

You are not doing anything wrong or right per-se choosing this approach as long as you decide for NoSql (or against) for the right reasons which include these considerations.

Answer (score 1):

My team and I discussed a similar scenario recently and we solved it by changing our CRUD approach to a DDD approach. Here is an example:

Given a traveler with a list of visited destinations.

If I have an event such a `destinationUpdated` then I should loop accross every travelers like you said, but does it make sens? What `destinationUpdated` means from a user point of view? Not much. Try to find the real user intent.

If the traveler made a mistake entering is visited destination then your event should be `travelerCorrectedDestination` which solve the problem because `travelerCorrectedDestination` now contains the travaler ID so you don't have to loop through all travelers anymore.

By applying a DDD approach problems usually solve by themselfs.